# Angular keypress event fires view every time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a basic angular app below but the strange thing is that every time a user types a message the view appears to be reloaded.

I'm unsure as to why this may happen since I'm using the track by qualitater.  Any help is appreciated

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("ChatApp", []);

mainApp.controller('ChatController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.linkify = function(inputText) {

    console.log("INPUT TYPE " + inputText);
  }


}]);
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>


<div id="main-window" class="main-content" style="padding-top:50px;">

  <div ng-app="ChatApp" ng-controller="ChatController">

    <div id="chatmcontainer" class="container-fluid">

      <ul id="chatbox" class="chat">
        <li ng-repeat="n in [41, 42, 43, 44] track by $index">
          <p>
            {{linkify(n)}}
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-7 bg-white" style="padding-right:20px;">
        <div class="input-group">

          <input ng-keypress="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0" ng-model-options="{
                       updateOn: 'blur'
                   }">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please format code ? It will be easy to help.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ? your linify only logs, so what exactly do you expect to happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{{::linkify(n)}}
```

in order to use one way binding.
I think it is redrawing the list because you use a function. I will try to find a more detailed explanation and I will edit this response.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Robert, it still seems to be re-drawing it even with the change :(